# XSL FO Table Cell Wrap Direction

Tags: xslt, newline, xsl-fo, word-wrap

I'm having an issue that I would think would be pretty straightforward to fix, but alas, I can't find the answer.

The problem: whenever the string inside a table cell is longer then the column width, it will create a new line/wrap the string. However, when it does this, it wraps the string upward rather than below.

For example:

```
Address|123 Fakie Street New York, NY
```

would become:

```
|123 Fakie Street  
Address|New York, NY
```

I want it like this:

```
Address|123 Fakie Street  
       |New York,NY
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds more like you are looking for vertical alignment..

Comment: Can you show the template that's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the vertical bar symbol indicated the cell border. I therefore think you are looking for vertical alignment. You can apply explicit vertical alignment on a table-cell using the display-align attribute, for example like this:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="35mm" border-style="solid">
    <fo:table-column column-width="20mm"/>
    <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>

    <fo:table-body font-size="7pt">
        <fo:table-row border-style="solid">
            <fo:table-cell display-align="before">
                <fo:block text-align="right">Address</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell display-align="before">
                <fo:block>123 Fakie Street New York, NY</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

HTH!